# is there a way to have sanctum on diffrent Vue Projects

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, session, cookies

Hello I'm using Sanctum To Auth users to the system I need if someone make log in on vue project num1 he be also be logged in on vue vue project num2

I have tried to use cookie like this

```
       $localeCookie = Cookie::forever('locale', 'en', null, null, null, false);

                // Delete authentication-related cookies
        $response = response()->json($data, 200)->withCookie(cookie()->forget('jwt_token'));

        return  $response->withCookie(cookie('jwt_token', $token, 360));
```

this returns a cookie when user logs in and it's working fine in and i can see it on the first vue project but it dosent go to vue project num 2

Comment: Does both project shares common database?

Comment: @ErJagdishPatel yes same Database and Same Laravel Project

Comment: you can create signed URL and then get user from there and login to project 2. Check documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/urls#signed-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Temporary signed URL.

```
Route::get('sign', function () {
     return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::temporarySignedRoute(
         'loginWithSignedUrl',
            now()->addMinutes(1),
         ['user' => 1]
     );
})->name('sign');

Route::get('loginWithSignedUrl/{user}', function (Request $request, $user) {
    if($request->hasValidSignature()) {
      auth()->loginUsingId($user);  
    } 
})->name('loginWithSignedUrl');
```

Comment: Thanks but the vue app will redirect to URL of other vue app how will i use it

Comment: There is option to redirect also. If you are using Inertia then you can redirect it like Inertia::location() or via javascript windows.location helper.

Comment: but this way it will redirect to API i want to redirect to vue app How Can i manage this

Comment: and if i have logged in then redirect from api it will not be logged in the next app

Comment: You can use similar logic where one app will hash users id and create token then share it with other project via link and decrypt it there and login in new project.

Comment: And in loginWithSignedUrl you can get user id and create sanctum token and return it to vue as json object so that it can be used to other api calls.

Comment: ok this is one idea 
so i cant use cookies between both vue apps

Comment: Cookies are stored for single domain as per my knowledge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255099/discussion-between-kareem-elsharkawy-and-jagdish-patel).